# Converting time constant to bandwidth of 1st order system

Tags: control-engineering, signal-processing, circuit-design

When the system is first order:

$1/(1+s\tau)$

Why is the bandwidth: $f_{-3db}=1/(2\pi \tau)$?

Where did the $2\pi$ come from? Why isn't it simply $1/\tau$? The unit of $2\pi$ is related to radian. But the unit of $f_{-3db}$ is $[1/second]$ so unit of $1/(2\pi\tau)$ does not seem to equate to Hz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unit of frequency is *not* really $1/\mathrm{second}$.

$$
1\mathrm{Hz} = 1 \frac{\mathrm{cycle}}{\mathrm{second}}=360\frac{\mathrm{degrees}}{\mathrm{second}}=2\pi\frac{\mathrm{radians}}{\mathrm{second}}
$$

*cycle*, *degrees*, *radians* are kind of *unitless* since they all represent *a fraction* of a whole.

<sup>The *unit* of `radians` is kind of *unitless* since angle in radians is found by $\frac{\mathrm{arc length}}{\mathrm{radius}}$</sup>

*Natural* unit of frequency is `radian/s`.
$$
\left|\frac{1}{1+s_{\text{(-3 dB)}}\tau}\right| = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\\
\implies 1+\omega_{\text{(-3 dB)}}^2\tau^2=2
\qquad (\text{letting }s = j \omega)\\
\implies \omega_{\text{(-3 dB)}} = \frac{1}{\tau}
$$
whre $\omega_{\text{(-3 dB)}}$ is the bandwidth frequency. Its unit is `radians/second`. To convert to `hertz`,
$$
f_{\text{(-3 dB)}}=\frac{\omega_{\text{(-3 dB)}}}{2\pi}
$$